# How do I get application menu to not go behind windows taskbar?

Tags: windows-10

When I right click on a program and it brings up an options menu, if it is near the bottom of the screen, it goes behind the windows task bar at the bottom of the screen.  This doesn't happen on other computers.  Is there a setting somewhere that controls this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old Windows bug. Nobody know what causes it and there exist
very few workarounds. It can appear but equally also disappear.

In the post
[Windows 10 tray menu behind taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305382/windows-10-tray-menu-behind-taskbar)
from 2016 (!) there is mentioned
[this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64568344/165358)
from 2020:

> I can confirm, that this seems to be a Windows bug which occurs
> randomly on my Windows 10 instance. It seems to happen when waking
> windows up from sleep after I docked or undocked my notebook from a
> docking station, where I use a different monitor setup. But it's hard
> to tell if this is the cause or not.
>
> If it happens, I run a batch script with following content:
>
> ```
> taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
> # Wait a few seconds
> ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1
> start explorer.exe
> ```
>
> This restarts Windows Explorer and all the tray menus start appearing
> in front of the task bar again.

You may create a `.bat` file with the above commands on the desktop,
and run it whenever this starts happening.